# Redirecting the user to a specific screen of my app after sliding over a notification to unlock

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my app , local notifications are displaying correctly. But,my doubt is,i need to redirect to specific screen in app while i'm slide the unlock to notification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep Linking iOS Push Notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105053/deep-linking-ios-push-notifications)

Comment: Its possible you need to do on your AppDelegate and implement the method


    **- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification;**

Comment: @drasick, already i used the same method. but don't know how to push to specific screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out,

You will get local notification in this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification;
```

or for remote notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

and after that you can push your screen i.e.

```
if(you are in another screen)
    push your required screen 
else 
    do nothing.
```

Comment: @user2776263 Suppose you are in background and you are in another screen when notification came then you are required to push your redirect screen.

Comment: sure. but still i'm not clear about how to give condition in if condition. give sample condition in if condition..

Comment: @user2776263 what you have used in your app either navigationController or tabbarcontroller?

Comment: both tabbarController and navigationController.. i used 5 tabs. when i slide it should move to 4 th screen of 2nd tab

Comment: @user2776263 if[tabbarcontroller.selectedviewcontroller isKindofClass your class] then you are already there else tabbarcontroller. setselectedindex=1. Now, From tabbarcontroller.viewcontrollers you will get an array of navigationcontroller then create its mutable copy and then use object index 1 of an array and push your array of viewcontroller accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Do the below in app delegate.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
   UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];

   if (state != UIApplicationStateActive)
   {
      // redirect to the next screen.
   }
}
```

Hope it will help you.