# How do I setup deep link for the Push Notification in Facebook Analytics?

Tags: push-notification, deep-linking, facebook-analytics

In the Facebook Analytics document, it said the Push Notification could deep link to a certain page in the app, but I cannot find how to setup the deep link in the "Push Notification" campaign.

Does anyone how to set it up? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Analytics supports two types of push campaign - standard push notifications and in-app notifications.

For standard push notifications, if you want to deep link you'll need to manually configure the push payload by enabling 'Attach JSON Data' (see [here for iOS docs on payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)). This existing stackoverflow answer explains how to deep-link in push - [Deep Linking iOS Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105053/deep-linking-ios-push-notifications). Basically you include some meta data that you handle in your app yourself and take the appropriate actions. See screenshot below with productIdToOpen parameter.

[image: Custom JSON Data]

For in-app notifications it's even easier. Assuming you've already setup a scheme for your app to handle deep-links from the web, you can just configure one of the buttons to use that scheme. See the screenshot below.

[image: Using custom schemes in in-app notifications]